# How can i track and manipulate data from my web browser usage?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I'm not going to be able to be as specific in this question as I'd like to, but I'll try my best to stick to SO guidelines.

I need to create some way to collect and process some very basic data from my google chrome browser. Specifically, i need to track the page urls i visit and have them automatically recorded in a hierarchal structure based on chronology of visit. Thus:

If i visit url 1, then url 2, then url 3, then go back to url 2, and from there navigate to url 4,

I want to make a program that records url 1 as the parent, url 2 as its child, and url 3/4 as the children of url 2.

I think it would be very simple to make, but i have no experience with this matter so was hoping for a pointer in the right direction. Do i make an applet, or an extension, or use an api?

Specifically, i want to make this in the hopes of improving my learning- I figure that if i can track the structure/relations of the data/pages i review as i browse through wikipedia, it will help me get a better overall grasp of the concept.

I understand this is not a very specific question, thus i'm just asking which general area i should start that would give me the capabilities to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome stores the history in a SQLite database (and I belive so does Firefox).

SQLite has bindings for many languages, so it should be fairly easy to read and process.